# Product of projective and affine line is not affine

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Why is $\mathbb{P}^{1} \times \mathbb{A}^{1}$ not isomorphic to an affine variety?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Every closed subset of an affine variety is affine.
But here the  closed subset $\mathbb P^1\times \lbrace 0 \rbrace \subset \mathbb{P}^{1} \times \mathbb{A}^{1}$ (why is it closed?) is isomorphic to $\mathbb P^1$ and thus not affine ( why?)

Comment: What's the definition of "affine"?

Comment: Dear Jonathan, the notion "affine" is basic in algebraic geometry: check the first pages of any book on the subject.

Comment: Dear user, yes it is a theorem, relying on the fact that $\mathbb P^2$ is normal. (It is the analogue of Hartogs's theorem in complex analysis).  However here the situation is far simpler: given two points on  an affine variety, there is a regular function  taking different values at the two points. This fails for $\mathbb P^1$, on which all regular functions are constant. So $\mathbb P^1$ is not affine!

Comment: Dear user, look at Ravi Vakil's  wonderful online notes (http://math.stanford.edu/~vakil/216blog/FOAGmay0212public.pdf), starting  page 285, 12.3.9

Comment: Dear @GeorgesElencwajg I am looking at Proposition 3.1.9 of Qing Liu which says $\text{Proj} (B\otimes_A C) \cong \text{Proj} B\times_{\text{Spec} A } \text{Spec} C$. Does this mean $\Bbb{P}^2 \cong \Bbb{P}^1 \times_k \Bbb{A}^1$?